# MVC changing Create form dynamically depending on selected option and saving it in database

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 4 `Models` Post, Car, Category, SubCategory. Car has a few extra attributes and also inherits everything from Post, Post `Model` includes attributes for CategoryID and SubCategoryID. I need to create one `View` that can change dynamically to be able to save cars as well. The user first see two `dropdown` list for categories and subcategories, after both selected, it loads the right `PartialView`. Its all fine, however I can not save it in the database for a few reasons.

Firstly I dont know where to declare the `model` for the page, should it be in the create `View` - meaning it can not be changed as I only want the input fields to appear and change dynamically but page should not be reloaded. It also means as `Car Model` has a few extra attributes, both `string` and `int`, I can not create a `ViewModel` that has all possible attributes as `string` is not `nullable`. 
If the `model` is declared in the `PartialView`, it means I can create separate `ViewModel` for Car and Post but the form tag will be in the `PartialView` and the `dropdown` lists for categories and subcategories are outside this form tag in the Create `View` as it should not change. When form posted I get an error as before I used `Request.Form["..ID"];` to get CategoryID and SubCategoryID. I need to get around this somehow.

I tried using `Ajax`, but this got an error saying null entry for CategoryID and SubCategoryID, only pass values within the form tag.

`Models`

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        

}
public class SubCategory
{        
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }        
}
public class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string MainPhotoPath { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedAt { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }        
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubCategoryID")]
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }        
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }

}
public class Car : Post
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int EngineSize { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public string FuelType { get; set; }
    public string Transmission { get; set; }
}
```

Create `View`

```
@using Mvc.CascadeDropDown

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h2>Add a new Post</h2>
        <h3 id="CityDiv">City: @ViewBag.Location</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @Html.Action("Menu")
        <div id="createNewPost">

        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#SubCategoryID").click(function () {
    var selectedSubCategory = $("#SubCategoryID").val();
    if (selectedSubCategory == 4) {
        var url = "/Posts/CarPartial/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#createNewPost").html(data);
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    }        
    else {
        var url = "/Posts/PostPartial/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#createNewPost").html(data);
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    }
});
$("#CreatePostFormID").submit(function () {
    var _categoryId = $("#CategoryID").val();
    var _subcategoryId = $("#SubCategoryID").val();
    var url = "/Posts/Create/";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { cId: _categoryId, subId: _subcategoryId },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("ok");
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
});
</script>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Menu to select categories and subcategories

```
@model PostIt.Models.DropDown

<h4>
Please choose a category first
</h4>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryModel, new SelectList(Model.CategoryModel, "CategoryID", "Name"), new { @id = "CategoryID", @class = "form-control col-md-offset-2 margin-bottom" })
<select id="SubCategoryID" name="SubCategoryID" class="form-control col-md-offset-2 margin-bottom"></select>

}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#CategoryID").click(function () {
        var _categoryId = $("#CategoryID").val();
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $("#SubCategoryID").html(procemessage).show();
        var url = "/Posts/GetSubCategoryById/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { categoryid: _categoryId },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>Select a subcategory</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option class='selectedSubCategory' value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }
                $("#CategoryID").val(_categoryId);
                $("#SubCategoryID").html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

`PartialView` loaded inside `createNewPost` `div` if subcategory only requires a Post `Model`

```
@model PostIt.Models.PostViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Posts", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "CreatePostFormID" }))
        {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Msg, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Msg, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Msg, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainPhotoPath, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MainPhotoPath, new { type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainPhotoPath, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="SubmitID" /> | @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index")
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
}
```

`ActionMethod` to create a Post.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,Msg,Price,PostCode,MainPhotoPath")] PostViewModel post, HttpPostedFileBase image, int cId, int subId)
    {
        Post newPost = new Post();
        //var cId = Request.Form["CategoryModel"];
        //var subId = Request.Form["SubCategoryID"];
        newPost.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(cId);
        newPost.SubCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(subId);
        newPost.Title = post.Title;
        newPost.Msg = post.Msg;
        newPost.Price = post.Price;
        newPost.PostCode = post.PostCode;
        newPost.PostedAt = DateTime.Now;
        newPost.Active = false;
        newPost.ApplicationUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        newPost.CityName = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["location"].Value);
        Debug.WriteLine(Request.Files.Count);

        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
        string fileName = file.FileName;
        int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
        if (fileSize >= 10)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Upload_Files/images/");
            newPost.MainPhotoPath = "~/Upload_Files/images/" + fileName;

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Creating new directory");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload_Files/images/" + fileName));
        }
        else
        {
            newPost.MainPhotoPath = "~/Images/no_image.png";
        }



        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(newPost);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View("Create", post);
    }
```

Comment: Word of advice, you need to create a simplified representation of your question and ask it in a concise and condensed way. People aren't too keen on doing your programming for you which is what it seems like when you dump all your code into a question. That and other people won't really benefit from a question formatted like this.

Comment: As I understand I can comment that: First you don´t need Partial View to do  Dropdown, just call other values with FK, Second: when you load correctly and populate your dropdown, don´t need to use Ajax to save into database, just read about it, google have all info to achieve it easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not mean to dump too much code and I have learned my lesson on that..

If anyone is struggling with the same problem, the answer is the following.

Declare the `model` in the `PartialView` with the `@using (Html.BeginForm` tag so you can create the form accordingly to the `model`. Create form can be changed dynamically via `Ajax` so essentially one create form could handle any models.

As `dropdown` lists including the values for necessary CategoryID and SubCategoryID are outside the form tag, it will not be passed to the controller and even if using `Ajax` on top, it will only disrupt it. First it will call the `ActionResult` but no value being passed for IDs, returns an error and will not even call the `Ajax` function.

To work around it, when creating the `PartialView` in the controller for the right `model`, I pass the ID values with it.

`Ajax` call to get Post `PartialView`

```
var url = "/Posts/PostPartial/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { cid : selectedCategory, sid : selectedSubCategory },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#createNewPost").html(data);
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
```

`ActionResult` inside the controller to return the right `PartialView`. In this case it is a Post.

```
public ActionResult PostPartial(int cid, int sid)
    {
        PostViewModel viewmodel = new PostViewModel();
        viewmodel.CategoryID = cid;
        viewmodel.SubCategoryID = sid;
        return PartialView("CreatePost", viewmodel);
    }
```

The above Create `ActionResult` works fine, however the `ViewModel` called PostViewModel must have attributes for CategoryID and SubCategoryID as well and must `bind` attributes in controller to Create `ActionResult`.